# I'm taking the escalator upstairs

Tags: grammar

I want to say "I'm taking the escalator to go upstairs". As "upstairs" can be used as an adverb, I think "I'm taking the escalator upstairs" may also be fine. Does it make any sense?

Comment: 'I'm going upstairs' normally means 'I'm climbing the stairs to the next floor'.  In somewhere like a department store where escalators are the main way of changing levels, you would probably say 'I'm going up to the next floor'. If you caught yourself saying 'I'm taking the escalator upstairs', I think you might laugh at yourself because it sounded a bit funny (an escalator isn't stairs).

Comment: @KateBunting - When I was little, and my mother took me to department stores or on the Underground, we sometimes rode on what she called a 'moving staircase'.

Comment: @KateBunting I used to speak to a colleague on the phone who worked in Ryde, on the Isle of Wight. She was a mainland girl who married an islander, and had lived there for 20 years. I asked her if all the things I had heard about Wight islanders were true. "Yes", she said, "Definitely!". She told me how in the late 1990s a department store had installed the first escalators on the island and when they were first running, people came from all over the island just to ride up and down on them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Well, the French do call them 'rolling (or mechanical) staircases'! (I still think of a moving walkway as a 'trottoir roulant' because the first one I encountered was in France.)

Comment: @KateBunting - I envied French hospital patients and disabled people their _fauteuils roulants_ when I first heard of them. They sounded very comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm taking the escalator **up**.

Using "upstairs" in the context of an escalator feels wrong. But it seems it's only in the context of an escalator.

Of course I can take the stairs upstairs, but I can also take an elevator upstairs, and a fireman's pole downstairs. Sound can travel upstairs or downstairs. The words "upstairs" and "downstairs" only refer to the direction of the floor(s) above or below.

It's only with "escalator" that these words are jarring, I think because escalators are so similar to stairs, but distinct.